# Calculate all value of a column based on the user

Tags: sql, sql-server

i have the table Charge_Money in my database with columns: NickName, Money...
This table have all credits that my users have been added in their accounts in game.
I want to calculate the three players who did most recharge (column Money) during the period, how can I do this?
ex:

```
NickName        Money
player1         150000
player2         140000
player3         120000
player4         500000
```

Above, we have player4, player1 and player 2 in top three places of the ranking.

Comment: Hint:  `ORDER BY`.  `TOP`.

Answer (score 2):

You can try following query:

```
Select top 3 DISTINCT NickName, Money
from Charge_Money
Order By Money DESC;
```

Answer (score 1):

Here I used this query:

```
select  NickName, Sum([Money])
from    Charge_Money CM
where  (select count(distinct [Money]) from Charge_Money where 
             [Money]>=CM.[Money])<=3
       AND [Date] Between 'Startdate' And 'Enddate'
Group by NickName
```

And got results as 3 players who did most sum(recharge) during the period(Startdate-Enddate)

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
SELECT TOP(3) NickName, SUM([Money]) OVER (partition by NickName) as s 
FROM Charge_Money
WHERE .... 
ORDER BY s DESC
```

Change Where clause as you need.

Answer (score 0):

I use this following query:

```
SELECT DISTINCT TOP 3 NickName, SUM(Money)
FROM Charge_Money WHERE MONTH(Date) = 01 AND Day(Date) >= 21 AND Day(Date) <= 31
GROUP BY NickName
ORDER BY SUM(Money) DESC
```

And got this below:

```
NickName            Money
player1             465200
p2                  300000
p3                  167400
```